# вывод значения функции при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python

Помогите с выводом значения random на экран

[image: первый экран]

вот такой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random 

def otvet():
    result = label2.configure(text=otvet, font="Arial 25")
    
def random():
    x = Entry
    x = int(x)
    otvet = random.randrange(1,x)
    return otvet
    
# окно программы
window = Tk()
window.title("Генератор Чисел")
window.geometry("300x250")

# верхняя строчка
label1 = Label(text="Введите колличество \nучастников", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.pack()
label1.place(x=45, y=30)

# текст посредине 
text1 = "Создано \nСпециально \nдля розыгрышей \nи конкурсов."
label2 = Label(text=text1, justify=CENTER, font="Arial 12")
label2.place(x=90, y=90) 

# поле для ввода числа
message = StringVar()
message_entry = Entry(width=6, justify=CENTER)
message_entry.place(x=220, y=39)

# нижняя кнопка
message_button = Button(text="Ищем Победителей", command=otvet)
message_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c")

 
window.mainloop()
```

вот что получается:

[image: значение]

Comment: Разве `x` не должен быть `message_entry.get()`?

Comment: да, разобрался, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы нигде не использовали функцию `random()`
2. Чтобы взять значение `Entry`, нужно было написать так: `message_entry.get()`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randrange


def otvet():
    result = label2.configure(text=random(), font="Arial 25") # заменил


def random():
    x = int(message_entry.get()) # заменил
    return randrange(1, x)


# окно программы
window = Tk()
window.title("Генератор Чисел")
window.geometry("300x250")

# верхняя строчка
label1 = Label(text="Введите колличество \nучастников", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.pack()
label1.place(x=45, y=30)

# текст посредине
text1 = "Создано \nСпециально \nдля розыгрышей \nи конкурсов."
label2 = Label(text=text1, justify=CENTER, font="Arial 12")
label2.place(x=90, y=90)

# поле для ввода числа
message = StringVar()
message_entry = Entry(width=6, justify=CENTER)
message_entry.place(x=220, y=39)

# нижняя кнопка
message_button = Button(text="Ищем Победителей", command=otvet)
message_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c")


window.mainloop()
```